# Extracting every n-th regex-statement

Tags: regex, perl, loops

I am having a file `input.dat` which looks like:

```
ZZZ 111
ABC 523
ABC 835
ADD 234
ZZZ 222
ABC 0007
2935
ABC 4
ABC 893
wdq
ZZZ 333
ABC 777
ABC 00
```

I am able to extract the string after `ABC` but I need to get every n-th appearance. So I can't distinguish with a regex solely and thought a loop could handle this. To get only every second entry on a line with ABC, I tried:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $i;
my @grepped
open(INFILE,"input.dat") or die "$!  Exiting.\n";
while (my $line = <INFILE>) {

    if ($line =~ /^ZZZ (\d+)/){
    push(@grepped,"$1\t")
    };

    $i=0;
    for ($line =~ /^ABC (\d+)/){
    $i+=1;
    if($i==2){ push(@grepped,"$1\n") };
    };
}
close(INFILE);
```

The loops aren't working properly and I don't know why. I am getting:

```
111 523
835
222 0007
4
333 777
00
```

instead of the desired:

```
111 835
222 4
333 00
```

Comment: Just matching against a regex does not read the next line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matching a line against a regular expression does not read the next line from the input file. You have to somehow remember the state for each iteration of the loop, for example by storing the number of times you have seen ABC in a variable. Do not forget to zero it once you encounter ZZZ:

```
my @grepped;
my $seen = 0;
while (my $line = <INFILE>) {
    if ($line =~ /^ZZZ (.*)/) {
        push @grepped, $1;
        $seen = 0;
    }
    if ($line =~ /^ABC (.*)/) {
        push @grepped, $1 if $seen++ == 1;
    }
}

print "$_\n" for @grepped;
```

Another option would be to read the next lines in an inner loop, but you have to be careful not to read past the next ZZZ.

Comment: Thx, this works. So my only fault was the position of the zeroing. I changed my `for`-loop with `if` once again and now I understand. I knew this was a stupid fault, thx for the fast help.

Answer (score 1):

I would store the numbers inside a hash and do some nice magic with them :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $grepped;
my $active_n;
my $active_l;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
  chomp $line;
  if ( $line =~ /^ZZZ/ ) {
    $active_l = $line =~ s/^ZZZ //r;
  } elsif ($line =~ /^ABC/) {
    $active_n = $line =~ s/^ABC //r;
  }
  if ($active_l && $active_n) {
      $grepped->{$active_l} = $active_n;
  }  
}

use Data::Dumper;
print map { "$_ => $grepped->{$_}\n"} sort keys $grepped;

__DATA__

ZZZ 111
ABC 523
ABC 835
ADD 234
ZZZ 222
ABC 0007
2935
ABC 4
ABC 893
wdq
ZZZ 333
ABC 777
ABC 00
```

EDIT:

My output:

```
111 => 835
222 => 893
333 => 00
```